# PayPal Parallel Payment IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have been stuck for days! I am trying to get the details from PayPal IPN from a parallel payment.

I need the two email addresses that money was sent to and the amount, also the status.

I am looking here:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIPN

These are the lines in my code where I try and get email and amount:

```
$Email1 = $_POST['transaction[0].receiver'];
$Email2 = $_POST['transaction[1].receiver'];
```

And amount part:

```
$Amount1 = $_POST['transaction[0].amount'];
$Amount2 =  $_POST['transaction[1].amount'];
```

I am use the IPN code from this page.

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/AU/en_AU/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt

Any help? The POST variables come up blank?

---

Update: I Have found this:

```
<source lang="php">
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 
// By Gleb Esman, gleb@memberwing.com, http://www.memberwing.com/
//
// Pull raw POST data.
// We need to pull raw data and build our own copy of $_POST in order to
// workaround of invalid POST keys that Adaptive IPN request uses.

$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$_YOUR_POST = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
    $_YOUR_POST[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
if (count($_YOUR_POST) < 3) {
  $_YOUR_POST = $_POST;
  $original_post_used = TRUE;
}
else
  $original_post_used = FALSE;

// Build final $_req postback request
// Paypal's IPN Sample
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'

if ($original_post_used) {
  $_req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
  foreach ($_YOUR_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $_req .= "&$key=$value";
  }
}
else
  $_req = $raw_post_data . '&cmd=_notify-validate';
// $_req is ready for postback to Paypal here...
$req = $_req;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



// PHP 4.1
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
//$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
//
//foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
//  $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
//  $req .= "&$key=$value";
//}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// throw all this junk into the local error log so we can see what happened!
function log_arr($item, $key) {
  $p .= "$key = $item";
  error_log(urldecode($p));
}
array_walk_recursive($_YOUR_POST, 'log_arr');
error_log(urldecode($req));

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
  fputs($fp, $header . $req);
  while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = fgets($fp, 1024);
    if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
// check the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment
    } else if (strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation
    }
  }
  fclose($fp);
}
?>
</source>
```

which produces this in log file:

```
[10-Dec-2011 07:13:50] transaction[0].id_for_sender_txn = xxxxx
[10-Dec-2011 07:13:50] log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction = xxx
[10-Dec-2011 07:13:50] transaction[0].receiver = xxxxx
[10-Dec-2011 07:13:50] action_type = xxxx

[10-Dec-2011 07:13:50] transaction[1].paymentType = xxx
[10-Dec-2011 07:13:50] transaction[0].amount = xxxx
[10-Dec-2011 07:13:50] charset = xxx
```

Can anyone tell me how to get these into variables as this is what is printed in log file?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$_POST['transaction']['0']['receiver']` and so on. Also, enable `E_ALL` error messages so you see notices about things like this. If that were enabled, and you checked your error log, you would have seen an undefined index notice. Also, if you're ever desperate to debug `$_POST/$_GET/whatever` stuff and it's not you controlling the request, you can always write the content to a file and examine it.

Comment: Yes tried that previously and did not work. Got this in log:

[10-Dec-2011 06:18:47] PHP Warning:  urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given     xxxxxxxx on line 22

Comment: You're building $_YOUR_POST as an array just a few lines earlier, and then trying to use it as a string.  I'm thinking that http_build_query might be useful.