# PHP/CodeIgniter PayPal IPN Invalid Validation

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter, paypal-ipn

I'm having a website build on CodeIgniter 2 and I'm using the CodeIgniter PayPal Lib. I have done everything neccessary and I'm now able to proceed payments. I receive an IPN data an I have it send to my e-mail. I have read the PayPal IPN Guide, but I couldn't find a solution there.

Evetything fine untill here and I'm happy with the result, but I'm concerned, because the PayPal IPN verification fails and I **cannot understand** where is the problem.

When I send an IPN test **from the sandbox test site I receive a valid IPN,** but when I make a payment **from my website the IPN validation fails**.

I'm logging all the data and in the both cases (valid or invalid) the payment is successful and i have a "SUCCESS!" message from PayPal.

**Things I have tryed**

1. Change the CSRF protection on/off
2. Change encoding (utf-8 | windows-1252)
3. Adding|Removing fields from my PayPal request

**Code I'm using**

The fields I'm using

```
$this->paypal_lib->add_field('business', 'name_1321715512_biz@gmail.com');
$this->paypal_lib->add_field('return', site_url('paypal/success'));
$this->paypal_lib->add_field('cancel_return', site_url('paypal/cancel'));
$this->paypal_lib->add_field('notify_url', site_url('contest/receive_ipn'));
$this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_name', 'Contest Subscribtion Payment (Test)');
$this->paypal_lib->add_field('amount', '30');
$this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_number', Y11-1329469079-12); // Reference number
$this->paypal_lib->add_field('quantity', '1');
$this->paypal_lib->add_field('charset', 'utf8');
$this->paypal_lib->add_field('custom', 1723); //This is an id that I need.
```

The post to PayPal for validation

```
$post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate";

if (isset($_POST)){
    foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value){
         $value = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $value);
         $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
         $post_string .= "&$field=$value";

         $this->ipn_data[$field] = $value; //this is part of the library
    }
}

$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($post_string) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

The code to verify the IPN

```
fputs ($fp, $header . $post_string);
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        // Send me e-mail - Verified
    } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        // Send me e-mail - Invalid
    }
}
fclose($fp);
```

**Also I'm posting the response I receive**

This one is the INVALID (then send from my website)

```
cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=30.00&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&address_status=unconfirmed&payer_id=LD9UMUWHD44GY&tax=0.00&address_street=Via+Unit+d%27Italia%2C+5783296&payment_date=02%3A19%3A29+Feb+17%2C+2012+PST&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=80127&first_name=Alexander&mc_fee=1.37&address_country_code=IT&address_name=Alexander+Videnov&notify_version=3.4&custom=1721&payer_status=verified&business=aviden_1321715512_biz%40gmail.com&address_country=Italy&address_city=Napoli&quantity=1&verify_sign=AF1YwvTycK97c-VCwQnfsdzArWAcAqZjskElh-FsmZ0s9HqL9BjFUKVH&payer_email=aviden_1329133801_per%40gmail.com&txn_id=32Y96385XJ0686735&payment_type=instant&last_name=Videnov&address_state=Napoli&receiver_email=aviden_1321715512_biz%40gmail.com&payment_fee=&receiver_id=TQVQ3ASRDBW28&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=Yicca+Contest+Subscribtion+Payment+%28Test%29&mc_currency=EUR&item_number=Y11-1329473936-12&residence_country=IT&test_ipn=1&handling_amount=0.00&transaction_subject=1721&payment_gross=&shipping=0.00&ipn_track_id=35382e1887f00
```

And this is the VERIFIED (when send from PayPal test site)

```
cmd=_notify-validate&test_ipn=1&payment_type=echeck&payment_date=02%3A28%3A24+Feb+17%2C+2012+PST&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123%2C+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=TESTSELLERID1&residence_country=US&item_name=something&item_number=AK-1234&quantity=1&shipping=3.04&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&txn_type=web_accept&txn_id=242171028&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&charset=windows-1252&verify_sign=An5ns1Kso7MWUdW4ErQKJJJ4qi4-Arge8MWjXZSo7fPSQf3xaqAOjrSH
```

**Two things I have noticed**

1. The order of the fields (the request) **is different** between IPN request send by my website and the one send from sandbox test site.
2. There is difference in the `notify_version` field. From my website (3.4) | From PayPal (2.1)

Did anybody expirienced the same problem with the validation. Is there something that I'm missing, or some way that I can debug more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're using adaptive payments or not, but I used this library: http://www.binpress.com/app/paypal-adaptive-payments-pro-codeigniter-library/140 and it works awesome and the author is very helpful.

See my question here: [Paypal IPN Issue with parallel payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048553/paypal-ipn-issue-with-parallel-payment). I've posted my paypal IPN code in the answer.

Comment: I found the answer in your post. I have changed `$post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate";` to `$post_string= 'cmd=_notify-validate&'.file_get_contents("php://input");` and removed the `foreach` loop. Now the IPN return VERIFIED. I have noticed that some of the chars in the two requests are different and I can guess that illegal characters was the reason of the INVALID return.

Answer (score 3):

I got this response from Paypal which might be relevant to you also:

Now we know from experience that special characters can be difficult to deal with during the IPN validation.
Basically, the character encoding that we use to send the IPN Message to your server needs to be matched by your IPN Handler when it posts the message back to the PayPal Systems for verification.

We've had a lot of success at resolving these issues by changing the language encoding options of the account to UTF-8.

Here's how you do it:
1. Please log in to your PayPal Account.

1. Then follow this link that will take you directly to the language encoding options: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-language-encoding
2. Click on the "More Options" Button.
3. Change both pull down menus to UTF-8 and click on save.

If you've specified a different character encoding in your code, please switch it to UTF-8 as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `CodeIgniter PayPal Lib` is outdated and bugged all the time. At least in my experience.

What I do, and I would recommend, is using the official PayPal SDK's and 'convert' them to CI.
This is fairly easy.

You can find these here:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks

Also do check out there docs:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-integration-guides#ec
You can't live without them!

Comment: I did all changes neccessary and I still have the INVALID responce. I have modified all the PayPal Lib and replacing it with the correct code, grabbed from the paypal website. Also for the test I have hardcoded the form with a fixed fields, but still no luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have updated my post with both the invalid and verified requests. Please have a look.